# How to manage big Loops in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

So I have this contract and the funder can retrieve the total amounts of a specific campaign through the getFundsByAddress function. The problem is that if a campaign has more than 30 thousand founders,the contract is not able to execute the code because it would need to go through the 30 thousand times so can find all the correct addresses

In the Rinkeby nework the max a loop it can reach is 30k, after that is returning 0

How can I resolve such cases?

```
contract CrowdFunding {
    struct Funder {
        address addr;
        uint amount;
    }

    struct Campaign {
        address beneficiary;
        uint numFunders;
        uint amount;
        mapping (uint => Funder) funders;
    }

    uint numCampaigns;
    Campaign[] public campaigns;

    function newCampaign() public returns (uint campaignID) {
        campaignID = campaigns.length++;
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        c.beneficiary = msg.sender;
    }

    function contribute(uint _campaignID, uint _amount) public {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[_campaignID];
        c.funders[c.numFunders++] = Funder({addr: msg.sender, amount: _amount});
        c.amount += 100;
    }

    // not tested
    function getFundsByAddress() public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[0];
        uint cont = c.numFunders;

        uint[] memory allAmount = new uint[](TotalAmountOfUser);

        uint counter = 0;

        for (uint i=0; i < cont; i++) {
           if (c.funders[counter].addr == msg.sender) {
               allAmount[amountCont] = c.funders[counter].amount;
           }
           counter++;
        }

        return allAmount;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on the amount of loops, only on the amount of gas you can spend on the processing. A block can only hold certain amount of gas, currently in the mainnet around 8 million (totalled from all the transactions in the block, see more at [Is there a max amount of gas per transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16825/is-there-a-max-amount-of-gas-per-transaction/16826)). If your transaction would require more gas (more processing) than that it will simply revert due to out of gas.

There is no direct way around the problem. The only solution you have is to refactor the code so that it doesn't perform so much processing in one transaction. In your case you could for example split the function in multiple parts, each checking a batch of 10000 addresses or something like that. Then you'll have to issue separate transactions to process everything.

In some sense an easier approach would be to refactor your code so that it simply doesn't require that much loops. If I understand your code correct you might want to try storing the loop checking instead in a mapping so you can simply retrieve data for `msg.sender` with something like `mymap[msg.sender].amount`. Possibly keep double bookkeeping (both in an array and in a mapping).

Answer (score 1):

Everything Lauri said.

As you've discovered, unbounded `for` loops are deadly. https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

Even if runs (less than 30,000) it might get too expensive to be practical or popular. To resolve that, you need a way to complete the operation in a single move. To accomplish that, you need to organize storage so the information you need is readily available without iteration.

This issue, and countless others like it is a recurring theme. I've been experimenting with a re-usable library and decided to see how it can help here. In this case, you can do without the `delete` capability so some optimization is possible.

This implementation uses the library for two concerns:

1. The set of campaigns that have been started.
2. The set of funders that have contributed to each campaign.

It does the accounting of campaign funder contributions *on-the-fly* so it isn't necessary to iterate the funders to get the funds raised for a campaign, or iterate the contributions to get the total funds sent (to all campaigns) by a funder. I also dropped the `amount` from `contribute()` as I expect what you really want is a `payable` function that accepts ether and accounts for it.

Other than that, I tried to accomodate the functions I see in your code.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

// https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/UnorderedKeySet

import "./HitchensUnorderedKeySet.sol";

contract CrowdFunding {

    using HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib for HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib.Set;

    mapping(address => uint) public funderTotalContributions;

    struct Campaign {
        uint totalRaised;
        address beneficiary;
        mapping(address => uint) funderContributions;
        HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib.Set funderSet;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => Campaign) campaigns;
    HitchensUnorderedKeySetLib.Set campaignSet;

    function newCampaign() public {
        bytes32 campaignId = genCampaignId();
        campaignSet.insert(campaignId);
        campaigns[campaignId].beneficiary = msg.sender;
    }
    function contribute(bytes32 campaignId) public payable {
        require(campaignSet.exists(campaignId), "Campaign does not exist.");
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignId];
        if(!c.funderSet.exists(addressToBytes32(msg.sender))) c.funderSet.insert(addressToBytes32(msg.sender));
        c.funderContributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funderTotalContributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        c.totalRaised += msg.value;
    }
    function getCampaignFundsByAddress(address funder, bytes32 campaignId) public view returns(uint) {
        return campaigns[campaignId].funderContributions[funder];
    }
    function getCampaignInfo(bytes32 campaignId) public view returns(uint, address, uint) {
        require(campaignSet.exists(campaignId), "Not a campaign.");
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignId];
        return (c.totalRaised, c.beneficiary, c.funderSet.count());
    }
    function getCampaignAtIndex(uint index) public view returns(bytes32) {
        return campaignSet.keyAtIndex(index);
    }
    function getCampaignFunderAtIndex(bytes32 campaignId, uint index) public view returns(address) {
        require(campaignSet.exists(campaignId));
        return bytes32ToAddress(campaigns[campaignId].funderSet.keyAtIndex(index));
    }

    // unique campaignIds

    function genCampaignId() private view returns(bytes32 campaignId) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, msg.sender, campaignSet.count()));
    }

    // type conversion

    function addressToBytes32(address a) private pure returns(bytes32) {
        return bytes32(uint(uint160(a)));
    }
    function bytes32ToAddress(bytes32 b) private pure returns(address) {
        return address(uint160(uint(b)));
    }

}
```

In case the `library` function isn't clear. It basically sets up a new `Set` type with methods to manage lists conveniently. Explainer: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-epilogue-e563e794fde.

No testing. No warranty. ;-)

The type conversions are there because the out-of-the-box library uses `bytes32` for keys. You could refactor it to use `address` keys with the caveat that they aren't as versitile.

Hope it helps.